# LightSwitch custom query with LINQ using delegates does not work

Tags: delegates, linq-to-entities, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have problems in designing an extended query in the ...`PreprocessQuery()` Method of a `LightSwitch` query.

1st of all, I tell you in a simplified way, what works:

```
partial void NeedHelp_PreprocessQuery(bool Admin, ref IQueryable<Device> query)
{
  // Some code...
  query = query.Where<Device>(d => d.IsAvailable());
}
```

The query does not show any compile error and does what it should do.

---

Now, when I try to put the logic into a method and use its delegate in the query, there's no compile error either, but I get an exception. Here is the code:

```
private bool Logic(Device TheDevice, bool Admin)
{
  return Admin ? true : TheDevice.IsAvailable();
}
partial void NeedHelp_PreprocessQuery(bool Admin, ref IQueryable<Device> query)
{
  // Some code...
  Func<Device, bool, bool> LogicDelegate = new Func<Device, bool, bool>(this.Logic);
  query = query.Where<Device>(d => LogicDelegate(d, Admin));
}
```

The Exception is in German, I try to translate the essential:

```
The expression is not supported. Expression:
Invoke(value(LightSwitchApplication.ApplicationDataService+<>c__DisplayClass4).LogicDelegate, d, value(LightSwitchApplication.ApplicationDataService+<>c__DisplayClass4).Admin)
Message of inner exception:
The type "ApplicationData.Implementation.Device" cannot be used for a parameter of type "LightSwitchApplication.Device".
```

Since I am only using `Device`, I do not understand this confusion between `ApplicationData.Implementation.Device` and `LightSwitchApplication.Device`! What am I doing wrong?
Or is this kind of call simply not possible in LightSwitch?

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for inline code in linq2sql - its just imagination ;).

When you do something as 'item.Trim()' behind the scenes this will be translate to the SQL command LTRIM(RTRIM(item))

You may check Views in MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I solved this now with a workaround, in which I added a new field into the table, where the date ticks are stored as a long int. This is managed in parallel to the original DateTime field... Not very nice, but works good and easily.